# Does discretization of continuous features also lose information about distance?

Tags: data-cleaning, preprocessing

During discretization, it "squashes" nearby values into one bin, losing a little bit of information along the way.

But doesn't it also lose information about distances of features? For example, if we have `height` as continuous feature, we can e. g. create bins `very small`, `small`, `medium`, `large` and `very large`. Isn't it problem, that once we have these categories, we lose information that `very small` and `small` are closer than `small` and `very large`?

This would be even worse for predicted feature - I would assume that regression that tries to predict `height` number would be much more successfull than classifier that tries to predict category of `height` discretized, because cost function of regression can account for a distance from correct height, but cost function of classifier could only answer "correct" or "not correct".

Yet I haven't found any mention about this when I've searched about discretization.

Are my assumptions incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. Also, sometime the binning could be arbitrary as well, but sometimes it depends on how you use the insight.

Using marketing as an example, we often see age grouped into buckets like 18-24, 25-34, etc.

Would a 34 year and 35-year old behave dramatically differently? Probably not. But then, it might still make sense to use such grouping, because many ad platform targeting tools use the same bin definition. It doesn't make sense logically but practically.

Of course, it really depends on the situation and the kind of analyses you need to do. For some distribution, you might want to do a log scale before you bin, etc.

Back to your example, if you feel that height should be a continuous feature and most models can handle it, is there a particular reason why you would want to discretize it?

Comment: I've often read about discretization being one of the solutions for getting rid of noise and improving models performance, but I guess that the fact that you'll lose information about distance is also important.